# IF condition in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have different food categories like breakfast,lunch,dinner.I want to show current time in my views.For that I use Carbon Api.But now I want that when user comes to website the category selects automatically according to the current time.Let say if user comes to website at 3 o' clock at day time then it automatically goes to Lunch category.How I can do this in laravel.I am new to laravel.

Comment: How are you getting the data, from the database? Or you want to retrieve all data from database and show them in view based on time?

Comment: I want to retrieve all data from database and show them in view based on time.I am able to retrieve data and show it on view but now I want to show it based on time.

Comment: As an example lets say if user comes to website at 7-9 o'clock in morning then it should go to the breakfast category automataically based on that time.

Comment: Oh! Do you want to redirect to different category routes based on time?

Comment: You should add time period field like `start_time` and `end_time` to your category table so at the time when you fetch category data you can match that in which time period the current time occurs.

Comment: @DhavalBharadva how I can match that time to the current time?

Comment: @MANI please check my answer I have write the logic that you can implement in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Carbon::now()->hour < $lunchTime && Carbon::now()->hour > $dinerTime)
{
    return view('breakfast') // Or however you want to show that category
}
```

etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below, please note that I have just show logic here so start_time and end_time value should be timestamp.

**categories table structure**

```
id  category_name     start_time    end_time
1   BreakFast         8:00:00 AM    11:30:00 AM
2   Lunch             11:30:00 AM   5:30:00 PM
3   Dinner            5:30:00 PM    5:30:00 PM
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php 
If conditional statement to check which category select based on current time
if(Carbon::now() > $start_time and Carbon::now() < $end_time){
    $selected = $id;
}
?>
```

**HTML Code**

```
// here your select category combo
<option value='0'>Select catgory</option>
<option value='1' <?php echo $selected=='1' ? 'selected': '' ?> >Breakfast</option>
<option value='2' <?php echo $selected=='2' ? 'selected': '' ?>>Lunch</option>
<option value='3' <?php echo $selected=='3' ? 'selected': '' ?>>Dinner</option>
```

Comment: I added the columns as u described.but I don't understand how can I implement the above logic in laravel.in my main page I listed all categories but I want when I enter in website it will automatically goes to that category according to the current time.